# how to validate file content in php if someone change the extension of the file and uploadt it?

Tags: php

I want to upload a .csv file in PHP and want to ensure that the file is in .csv format. suppose if someone upload image file by changing the extension.

Comment: So have a validation on the backend for file extensions.

Comment: Why would your validation code care what the extension is?

Comment: sir i want to make sure that the uploaded file is in csv format. so that i could upload its data to the database. but if some one rename the image file and its extension to .csv. than i do not know how to handle it

Comment: @ishtiaq When you read the file, you can check if you are getting proper data while reading  the file(like NULL or false). You can also have a check on column headers etc just to make sure the data is in correct format.

Comment: Does your site process the uploaded CSV files or just store them? If it processes them, then you are already doing the robust error handling and shouldn't need another preliminary step; just treat it as a CSV and handle errors.

Comment: thanks sir @vivek_23  for your valueable suggestions

Comment: thanks sir  @Jonathon Reinhart for your valueable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If it's a CSV, you can use `fgetcsv()` and check for `null` or `false`.

```
$handle = fopen("uploaded_file.csv");
if(!($csvContent = fgetcsv($handle) == false)) {
    //invalid CSV
}
```

Comment: What validtion does `fgetcsv` by itself do on the file?

Comment: Apparently, I did get some binary code with fgetcsv() on a gif file when renamed to have a .csv extension.

Comment: It doesn't really do any validation, but it tries to read the CSV, and if it fails, it returns an error. Therefore, it's a relatively safe way to "validate" a csv file

Comment: @YUNOWORK A check on content of data seems to be necessary, as I got a binary string from reading from a gif(when being renamed to a .csv) and not exactly `false`.

Comment: That's weird, I'm using the same code for several importers and they work without problems, return ``false`` if it's not a csv. Maybe it's a configuration problem?

Comment: @YUNOWORK You will have to tag me since there are more than 2 in the conversation. Also, I actually have a gif at my end which I renamed to `test.csv` and it give me [this](https://imgur.com/a/uqkiGZI)

Comment: @Y U NO WORK should i use this code to read file from its temporary location. and if it fails then further procedure going to abort.